# Adding server-side event to extender control

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have an extender control that raises a textbox's `OnTextChanged` event 500ms after the user has finished typing. The problem with this is that `OnTextChanged` gets raised when the textbox loses focus, which causes problems (because of the postback).

What I'd like to do is give the extender control its own server-side event (say, `OnDelayedSubmit`) so I can handle it separately. The event will originate in the extender control's behavior script (after the 500ms delay), so putting a `__doPostBack` in `onchanged` is not an option.

Can anyone shed light on how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After plenty of reading up on extender controls and JavaScript, I've cobbled together a solution that seems to be working so far.

The main trick was getting the necessary postback code from server-side to the client-side behavior script. I did this by using an `ExtenderControlProperty` (which is set in the control's `OnPreRender` function), and then eval'd in the behavior script. The rest was basic event-handling stuff.

So now my extender control's `.cs` file looks something like this:

```
public class DelayedSubmitExtender : ExtenderControlBase, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    // This is where we'll give the behavior script the necessary code for the 
    // postback event
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        string postback = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "DelayedSubmit") + ";";
        PostBackEvent = postback;
    }

    // This property matches up with a pair of get & set functions in the behavior script
    [ExtenderControlProperty]
    public string PostBackEvent
    {
        get
        {
            return GetPropertyValue<string>("PostBackEvent", "");
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue<string>("PostBackEvent", value);
        }
    }

    // The event handling stuff
    public event EventHandler Submit;  // Our event

    protected void OnSubmit(EventArgs e)  // Called to raise the event
    {
        if (Submit != null)
        {
            Submit(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)  // From IPostBackEventHandler
    {
        if (eventArgument == "DelayedSubmit")
        {
            OnSubmit(new EventArgs());
        }
    }

}
```

And my behavior script looks something like this:

```
DelayedSubmitBehavior = function(element) {
    DelayedSubmitBehavior.initializeBase(this, [element]);

    this._postBackEvent = null; // Stores the script required for the postback
}

DelayedSubmitBehavior.prototype = {
    // Delayed submit code removed for brevity, but normally this would be where 
    // initialize, dispose, and client-side event handlers would go

    // This is the client-side part of the PostBackEvent property
    get_PostBackEvent: function() {
        return this._postBackEvent;
    },
    set_PostBackEvent: function(value) {
        this._postBackEvent = value;
    }

    // This is the client-side event handler where the postback is initiated from
    _onTimerTick: function(sender, eventArgs) {
        // The following line evaluates the string var as javascript,
        // which will cause the desired postback
        eval(this._postBackEvent);
    }
}
```

Now the server-side event can be handled the same way you'd handle an event on any other control.