# What is the namespace of Get/SetPropertyValue in Extender Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, extender

I'm creating an extender control by referring [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22541/ASP-NET-AJAX-Extender-for-multicolumn-drag-and-dro), but I'm facing hard time to get/know the namespace of `GetPropertyValue` and `SetPropertyValue` which used in the example like this:

```
    [ExtenderControlProperty]
    public string DragItemHandleClass
    {
        get
        {
            return GetPropertyValue<String>("DragItemHandleClass", string.Empty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue<String>("DragItemHandleClass", value);
        }
    }
```

I observed this on other [sites too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555/adding-server-side-event-to-extender-control), so its not a custom implementation and I couldn't find it on `AjaxControlToolkit`. Could some one please guide me on this?

Comment: wow...exactly! thank you. Please post it as answer, will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExtenderControlBase` provides implementation for these generic methods. Hence, deriving your extender from it resolves the issue here.